# Getting null TagManager in AEM 6.1

Tags: aem, tagging

Trying to fetch the list of all the resources tagged with the specific tag. Following is the line used to fetch the TagManager from ResourceResolver

```
TagManager tagManager = resourceResolver.adaptTo(TagManager.class);
```

But getting null TagManager. 
Also, when I am trying to bind JcrTagManagerFactory, the service is failing as the JcrTagManagerFactory could not be bind. I could see JcrTagManagerFactory service running in console.

```
@Reference
JcrTagManagerFactory jcrTagManagerFactory;
```

Any suggestions? Am I missing anything?

Comment: is this from author or dispatcher? If from dispatcher there is lot of chance this wont work. From dispatcher the user will be 'anonymous' and will not have permissions to tagmanager. And will return null. For dispatcher calls, we should create separate system admin user, provided access to /etc/tags and then login using the system user

Comment: @SaravanaPrakash- from author...for admin user